# How do I append a formatted string into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcpy

I have the following:

```
char rank[100][100];
int score = 5;

strcpy(rank[0], "%d" score);
```

However, `strcpy()` does not accept these arguments. Is there any way to append a formatted string into my array?

Comment: You want [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/snprintf).

Comment: is that appending or copying? have similar doubts on sprintf family, unless handled very carefully will provide very unusual results

Comment: strcpy() does NOT evaluate format specifiers.  A read of the man page for strcpy() will fill you in on the details.   sprintf()  does evaluate format specifiers.   suggest replace `strcpy` with `sprintf` with appropriate parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sprintf`:

```
char rank[100][100];
int score;

sprintf(rank[0], "%d", score);
```

Note however that [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) **is the buffer overflow-safe alternative.**

Comment: Better use `int w = snprintf(rank[0], sizeof(rank[0]), "%d", score);` then test that `w` is less than `sizeof(rank[0])` -practically that would *always* be the case

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this with `strcpy()`.

However, you can make use of [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) first to prepare your string and the use the same as the second argument of `strcpy()`.

FWIW, in this case, you can directly use `snprintf()` on `rank[n]`, also.